# automapper dto to viewmodel

Tags: viewmodel, automapper, dto

How can I map my dto to my ViewModel, knowing the following :

My dto:

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public int myProperty{get; set;}
 }
```

my viewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
 public SomeClass theDto {get; set;}

 public int someExtraProperty
}
```

So, my ViewModel contains my dto + other properties. How can I easily map the dto object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the following seems to work !

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<SomeClass, MyViewModel>().ForMember(d => d.theDto, s => s.MapFrom(src => src));
```